# generating user input from the result of previous user input in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I want user input based on the result of the previous input data.
This is what i'm trying to do:

```
 no_of_children = int(input("How many children are u enrolling?")) 
 if no_of_children >= 2:
   print("Please provide their names accordingly")
   child_name= input("Child's name:")
```

So if the `no_of_children = 4`, I should have 4 `child_name` inputs

Comment: Could you include what the result of the code above is? Does it error out, does it produce an incorrect result, etc.?

Comment: How many children are u enrolling? 4
Please provide their names accordingly
Child's name:Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works fine for me. Plus you have the names saved in a list:

```
no_of_children = int(input("How many children are u enrolling?")) 
child_names = []
if no_of_children >= 1:
    print("Please provide their names accordingly")
    for i in range(no_of_children):
        child_names.append(input("Name of child #{}:".format(i+1)))
```

The output looks like this:

How many children are u enrolling?4

Please provide their names accordingly

Name of child #1:John

Name of child #2:Sarah

Name of child #3:Jim

Name of child #4:Mike

Answer (score 0):

You should use `for` loop for getting the data from the user. Your code should look something like this.

```
no_of_children = int(input("How many children are u enrolling?")) 
for child in range(no_of_children):
   print("Please provide their names accordingly")
   child_name= input("Child's name:")
```